# How to create one or more polygons from OpenStreetMap boundary relation in C#?

Tags: c#, openstreetmap, nettopologysuite

I am using [OSMSharp](https://github.com/OsmSharp/core) (C# OpenStreetMap library) to get the boundary of a region (e.g. a city, state) from an osm.pbf file. The structure I get is a [Relation](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Relation) containing [Ways](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Way) which consists of [Nodes](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Node). The Ways contains a set of WGS84 points (lat., long.) represented by the Nodes that are part of the Ways. Combining the Ways (Ways are like lines with multiple points) can result in one or more polygons representing the area of region. I need help to get there.

The order of the ways is not sequential and it is unclear which way is part of which region polygon (if there are multiple). I thought the C# NetTopologySuite has a method to combine these ways to one or more polygons in order to use [OsmSharp.FilterSpatial](https://github.com/OsmSharp/core/tree/develop/samples/Sample.GeoFilter) method. But I cannot find it. Does any body know a C# library that can perform this action?

Answer (score 5):

Found the solution. The NetTopologySuite [Polygonizer](http://nettopologysuite.github.io/NetTopologySuite/api/NetTopologySuite.Operation.Polygonize.Polygonizer.html?q=polygonizer) is a good fit to fix this problem.

```cs
List<IGeometry> lines = new List<IGeometry>();
lines.Add(new LineString(new Coordinate[] { new Coordinate(0, 0), new Coordinate(1, 0) }));
lines.Add(new LineString(new Coordinate[] { new Coordinate(1, 0), new Coordinate(1, 1) }));
lines.Add(new LineString(new Coordinate[] { new Coordinate(1, 1), new Coordinate(0, 1) }));
lines.Add(new LineString(new Coordinate[] { new Coordinate(0, 1), new Coordinate(0, 0) }));

Polygonizer polygonizer = new Polygonizer();
polygonizer.Add(lines);

IList<IGeometry> polys = polygonizer.GetPolygons();
```